# Excluir linha de tabela dinâmica através de botão na caixa de diálogo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

Como eu excluo uma linha de uma tabela dinâmica através de uma caixa de diálogo de confirmação (*modal*)?

Até o momento eu consigo excluir apenas usando diretamente o botão excluir da própria linha na tabela, mas eu gostaria que houvesse um modal com uma confirmação, antes de a excluir.

Na tabela vem um botão remover aí eu clico nele e abre uma caixa de diálogo perguntando:

> " Você tem certeza que deseja excluir? <kbd>Sim</kbd> <kbd>Não</kbd>"

O problema é que eu não estou conseguindo fazer excluir através desse botão <kbd>Sim</kbd>, apenas funciona quando clico no icon "remover" direto na tabela.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
<table id="lista-tarefas" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead class="bg-header-tb">
      <th class="text-center text-uppercase">Nome</th>
      <th class="text-center text-uppercase">Tipo</th>
      <th class="text-center text-uppercase">Ação</th>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td>Tarefa 1</td>
         <td>Perguntas e Respostas</td>
         <td class="text-center">
            <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" class="acoes-btn">
               <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" >
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
               </button>
            </p>
            <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Excluir" class="acoes-btn">
               <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete">
               <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button>
            </p>
         </td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>

<!--caixa de dialogo-->
<div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
   <div class="modal-dialog">
      <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Excluir tarefa</h4>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">
            <div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Tem certeza que deseja excluir a tarefa?</div>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-footer ">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Sim</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Não</button>
         </div>
      </div>
      <!-- /.modal-content --> 
   </div>
   <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
</div>
```

Comment: Olá Isabella Meirelles, pode dizer exatamente como ocorre essa exclusão?

Comment: Olá @LeoCaracciolo vou clicar no icon delete na tabela e vai abrir uma caixa de dialogo perguntando se desejo excluir, aí apertando no sim a linha da tabela que eu selecionei será excluida, eu não consigo fazer através da caixa de dialogo, somente direto pelo icon da tabela

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para isso tens que adicionar um *trigger* ao botão <kbd>SIM</kbd> do modal que irá lançar a função para eliminar aquilo que queiras, que neste caso será a linha (`td`) inteira da tabela.

Eu recomendaria também  adicionar um *container/wrapper* em todo esse exerto de código para apontar mais precisamente para o elemento desejado sem afetar outros que por coincidência possam vir a ter os mesmos nomes de classes ou elementos etc...

> ### Edição:
>
> Evento `click` modificado e preparado para lidar com novos elementos adicionados dinamicamente. Exemplo online no jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/j6u8p9jo/

Eis um exemplo abaixo:

```js
var $thatRow;

// Quando ocorre um click em uma linha da tabela tr,
// salva essa linha como uma variável global para poder ser usada como ponto de referência onde o click ocorreu
$(document).on('click', '#lista-tarefas tbody tr', function(){
    $thatRow = $(this);
});

// Aponta para a nova class adicionada ao botão "SIM" do modal
$('#li-content-wrapper .excluir-trigger').on('click', function(){
    alert('Linha da tabela removida com sucesso!');
    // Aqui remove a linha referida
    $thatRow.hide(); // ou usando remove() do jQuery dependendo do que queira
});
```

```html
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div id="li-content-wrapper">
    <table id="lista-tarefas" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
        <thead class="bg-header-tb">
            <th class="text-center text-uppercase">Nome</th>
            <th class="text-center text-uppercase">Tipo</th>
            <th class="text-center text-uppercase">Ação</th>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td>Tarefa 1</td>
                <td>Perguntas e Respostas</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" class="acoes-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" >
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                    <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Excluir" class="acoes-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Tarefa 1</td>
                <td>Perguntas e Respostas</td>
                <td class="text-center">
                    <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Editar" class="acoes-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-title="Edit" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#edit" >
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                    <p data-placement="top" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Excluir" class="acoes-btn">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-title="Delete" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#delete">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                        </button>
                    </p>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>

    <!--caixa de dialogo-->
    <div class="modal fade" id="delete" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="edit" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Excluir tarefa</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-warning-sign"></span> Tem certeza que deseja excluir a tarefa?</div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer ">
                    <!-- AQUI ADICIONA A NOVA CLASS ".excluir-trigger" (Trigger) AO BOTÃO "SIM" -->
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary excluir-trigger" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span> Sim</button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Não</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <!-- /.modal-content --> 
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-dialog --> 
    </div>
    ExecutarCopiar para uma nova respostaEsconder resultado
</div>
```

Comment: @Chun testei e funcionou mas ele tá excluindo todos os itens dá tabela, sabe o que pode ser?

Comment: Já editei a minha resposta @IsabellaMeirelles espero ter ajudado :)

Comment: @Chun eu vou aplicar a solução hoje e te dou o feedback, obrigada!!!!!!!!

Comment: @Chun funcionou perfeitamente naqueles que estão adicionados diretamente no html mas os dinamicos não exclui e não estoura erro, imagina o que pode ser?

Comment: @Chun quando excluo diretamente no icon lixeira da tabela ele consegue excluir os adicionados dinamicamente(isso no meu codigo anterior) mas pela caixa de dialogo quando adiciono uma nova linha ele não exclui e não estoura erro :/

Comment: @Chun estou adicionando as novas linha assim: https://jsfiddle.net/jgmoLnov/

Comment: Já fiz a alteração na minha resposta @IsabellaMeirelles . Agora está a funcionar corretamente. Exemplo online: https://jsfiddle.net/shuffledPixels/j6u8p9jo/

Comment: @chun obrigada!!!